# How to use a macro to store the default pgfplot properties

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, graphics

I have some default settings for my pgfplots plots, such as `xlabel`, `ylabel`, `width` and so on. Since I have a large number of such plots and don't want to repeat all the properties, I want to store them in a command and use that command to print those properties. Is it possible? How can I get around to this?

**Note** I do not want to change the default settings of pgfplots. I want to print a certain set of properties using one single command.

Here is an example of properties:

```
\newcommand{\tikzDefaults}[0]{
                        xlabel=$k$,
                        ylabel=$C$,
                        width=6.4cm,
                        height=5cm,
                        cycle list name=best,
                        enlargelimits=0,
                        every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
                        legend entries={A1, A2, S1, S2, E1, E2, FF},
                        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
                        x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.15)},anchor=north},
                        y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.18,.5)},anchor=south},
}
```

Comment: You can change the settings of pgfpplots inside an environment or group without changing them globally. That way, after defining a macro `\foo` you can do `\expandafter\pgfplotsset\expandafter{\foo}`.

Comment: @Manuel where should I put this command?

Comment: I have a few of such settings. If I change the default fonts, It will be applied to other plots that I want them to be different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\pgfplotsset{tikzDefaults/.style=
  {xlabel=$k$,
   ylabel=$C$,
   width=6.4cm,
   height=5cm,
   cycle list name=best,
   enlargelimits=0,
   every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
   legend entries={A1, A2, S1, S2, E1, E2, FF},
   x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
   x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.15)},anchor=north},
   y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.18,.5)},anchor=south},}}
```

And then use `tikzDefaults` as an option. It “saves” all of the options inside of it.

Comment: I cannot use the option `ymode` in this way. Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: Not that I know. May be post another question?

Answer (score 5):

Manuel's solution is the way to go in most cases, but in case you truly do want a switch-type command to turn these settings on, it is possible.

The example shows limiting the effect of the command using the concept of grouping. Until the group ends, all `axis` environments after the command `\tikzDefaults` will pick up the key-value pairs you've defined in the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,width=3.5cm}% just to fit the example on a single page

\newcommand{\tikzDefaults}[0]{
  \pgfplotsset{
    xlabel=$k$,
    ylabel=$C$,
    width=6.4cm,
    height=5cm,
%    cycle list name=best, % I don't have this cycle list defined
    enlargelimits=0,
    every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
    legend entries={A1, A2, S1, S2, E1, E2, FF},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.15)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.18,.5)},anchor=south},
  }
}

\newcommand{\drawplot}[1]{% just for the example
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title=#1]
    \addplot {x};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\drawplot{Outside group; before outer command}
{% the start of a group
\drawplot{Inside group; before outer and inner commands}
\tikzDefaults
\drawplot{Inside group; after inner command}
}% the end of the group
\drawplot{Outside group; before outer command}
\tikzDefaults
\drawplot{Outside group; after outer command}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The point that you just made is interesting. But a good point about Manuel's solution is that I can use the name of that group/command as a property.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to print the values of variables through `\pgfmathprintnumber`, e.g. within an axis environment I can print the `xmax` value `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotsxmax}`, where `\newcommand{\pgfplotsxmax}{\pgfplots@xmax}` is defined in the preamble

Comment: For the commend that I explained, I used `\pgfmathprintnumber{\tikzDefaults}` but it doesn't work.